# animation and game development tutorial for iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, ipad

Can anybody suggest a good game development and animation tutorial for iphone

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What kind of animation? From the art perspective or the code perspective?  What about what you're doing is specific to the iPhone?

Comment: Voted to close; this is incredibly broad.

Comment: see also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-are-the-best-iphone-game-development-resources

Answer (score 2):

You might check out O'Reilly's iPhone Game Development book if you're talking about more 2D sprite oriented animation (think "Angry Birds").

But if you're talking 3D style animation, you'll need to decide whether you're going to write it yourself (a lot of work) or use a commercial game engine like Unity 3D or Unreal.

Answer (score 0):

Without any information on your requirements, i can only link to the most popular iOS game development environments around, which are [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) and [unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/)